# Pandas .to_sql is not inserting any records for a dataframe I want to send to sql. Are there any generic reasons why this might be the case?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, pandas

Pandas .to_sql is not inserting any records for a dataframe I want to send to sql. Are there any generic reasons why this might be the case?

- I am not getting any error messages. The column names appear fine, but the table is entirely empty.
- When I try to send over a single column (i.e. data.ix[2]), it actually works.
- However, if I try to send over more than one column (data.ix[1:3]), I again get a completely blank table in sql.

I have been using this code for other dataframes and have never encountered this problem. It still runs for other dataframes in my set.

Comment: Are you using an SQLAlchemy engine or raw connection string in `to_sql`?

Comment: the connection is made using sqlalchemy...

Comment: and I realized yesterday that when I try to push to SQL Server, it goes through, but when I try to push to psql it doesn't. Driving me completely bonkers.

Comment: Please show attempted `to_sql` code as it can be how it is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem - it was becomes some of the column headers had '%' in it.

I accidentally discovered this reason for the empty tables when I tried to use io and copy_from a temporary csv, instead of to_sql. I got a transaction error based on a % placeholder error.

Again, this is specific to passing to PSQL; it went through to SQL Server without a hitch.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing same issue because dot was added in header. remove dot then it will work.